# Mockito "when" possibilities

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, stubbing

I'm discovering Mockito and generally "mocks".
I want a method to return a value each time she's called.

So i did

```
CommonJMSProducer mockedJMS = mock(CommonJMSProducer.class);
when(mockedJMS.sendMessage(any(ActiveMQTextMessage.class), anyString()))
            .thenReturn(null);
```

But after I call another method who will call the previous one and my mock is never used.
So, my question is, the "when" is only effective when I use mockedJMS or always the object is created ?

In my test, I have a call to a service like this

```
this.request("api/receiver")
            .setHeader("TYPE", "ACCESREFUSE")
            .setHeader("APPLICATION", "Bruno Appli")
            .setHeader("TOMCAT", "tomcat1")
            .setHeader("SERVER", "server1")
            .post("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><ACCESREFUSE><IDOper>0002</IDOper><DateEvt>131015144340</DateEvt><IDEvt>0</IDEvt><IDJoueur>123456789</IDJoueur><HashJoueur>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000</HashJoueur><IDSession>301090</IDSession><IPJoueur>81.252.190.129</IPJoueur><TypAg>JC</TypAg><CauseRefus>Interdiction temporaire</CauseRefus><TypeRefus>AutoInterdit</TypeRefus></ACCESREFUSE>");
```

And inside, a call off the sendMessage method.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Your "`when`" only relates to `mockedJMS` - not to every object of the `CommonJMSProducer` class.

Comment: hmm ok. do you know if what i want is possible ? thanks

Comment: To be honest, I don't fully understand what you want.  How does the `CommonJMSProducer`  get set inside the class that you're testing?

Comment: Well I was thinking that everytime the CommonJMSProducer is called, the result whould be null.

Comment: OK, which `CommonJMSProducer` object?  How does it get into the place where you're calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `when` only applies to the object instance (in your case, `mockedJMS`).

If you are expecting your mocked object to be used in other places, you must wire it up appropriately in those places - for example via code or a DI framework.